Removing paint from Terrazzo
I have floors that are original terrazzo but pretty neglected. I plan on renting a floor machine and some diamond disks to resurface it and then I'll polish it with a burnisher. But before I tackle any of that, the geniuses before me decided to paint the floors. Would something like ZEP floor stripper work to take that off as well as the years of dirt build up? Or should I use a paint thinner on that area then a stripper on the whole floor once the paint is gone? The paint is only on half of the floors but I don't want to cause more damage by using the paint thinner and cause myself more work. I'd love to be able to hire someone to do it, but the $15k-20k I was quoted just isn't in the budget right now.
Thanks for any advice!

how to remove it depends on the paint, I would expect floor strippers not to attack painted baseboards. so probably less than fully effective on the painted floor.

heat gun and scraping
